# Setting ValidationError message for specific element in list

Tags: java, validation, jackson, message, playback

Currently, I am implementing custom validation in play framework, Java.
I have a class which contains a list of elements:

```
public class StandardRequest{
...
private List<@Valid StandardMaterial> materials;
...
//getters setters
```

And StandardMaterial class has a validation logic inside it:

```
@Validate
public class StandardMaterial  extends Material implements Validatable<ValidationError> {
private Integer condition_value;
...
 @Override
    public ValidationError validate() {
          if(condition_value < 0 || condition_value > 100){
                        return new ValidationError("materials","must be integer between 0 and 100");
           }
```

The input json for the above class is so:

```
"materials": [{"material_number": "1", "condition_type":"A1","condition_value": "-15"},
                {"material_number": 2","condition_type":"A2","condition_value": "-25"}]
```

This produces a validation error message in response as so:

```
 "validations": [
            {
                "property": "materials",
                "message": "must be integer between 0 and 100"
            },
            {
                "property": "materials",
                "message": "must be integer between 0 and 100"
            }
        ],
```

What I can not achieve now to have the index of the material specified, I need to get this response:

```
"validations": [
            {
                "property": "materials[0]",
                "message": "must be integer between 0 and 100"
            },
            {
                "property": "materials[1]",
                "message": "must be integer between 0 and 100"
            }
        ],

Any ideas how can I do that?
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Edit your StandardMaterial class like below**

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;

public class StandardMaterial {

@Size(value=0,message="must be greater than or equal to 0")
@Size(value=100,message="must be less than or equal to 100")
private Integer condition_value;

}
```

**2. Create Separate Class for Handling this type of errors from any class globally by using @RestControllerAdvise**

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobleExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

@Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
            HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {

//Get All Errors
List<FieldError> errors = ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();

//Iterate and add to your custom object
for(FieldError e:errors){
    e.getDefaultMessage();//Your Error Message
    e.getField();//Field Name with index
}

}

}
```

This way you can do it...i have not shown everything..but you will get idea about how to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My project is in play framework so not sure if the same solution would apply there. Don't know the proper way to adapt your solution there in play framework.